# Wrong axis values on log graph in R

Tags: r, graph, axis

I am trying to make a simple log graph, both axes are log scale. The (actual) x-axis values range from 1E-7 to 1, and y-axis values range 1E-9 to 1. As you can see in the attached image they go below 0.

[image: photo of incorrect axis]

How can I fix this?
I am plotting it by:

```
alpha = read.csv(file = "alpha.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ',')
plot (log(alpha))
```

Comment: Do `dput(alpha)`  and paste it into your question so we can inspect the data, otherwise there's no way for anyone else to troubleshoot

Comment: Maybe what you want is `plot(alpha, log = "xy")` from `?plot.default`. Since the log of 1e-9 is in fact -9 and the log of 1 is zero, your current approach plots the logs of the values, not the values on a log scale.

Comment: or use `log10(alpha)` to get what you (probably) expected.

Comment: The response from Bryan Hanson worked! It was foolish of me not to realize that the graph was showing the log of the value. Thanks again!